# How can I add Google Profile badge to Gmail signature

Tags: gmail, email-signature

Okay so I read [here](http://blog.cartercole.com/2009/09/more-fun-with-google-profile.html?showComment=1285614574086#c3303330208678623312) how to pull up your Google Profile badge by itself. But can anybody figure out a way to add it to my GMail signature?  Seems like a no-brainer for Google to self promote this way.  Does it need to be submitted as a GMail Lab? Also adding a static image of this with the links broken would not do.

Edit: Now that I have my answer lets suggest this to Gmail Labs by Starring [this feature request](http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/browse_thread/thread/f258a72549b6224e#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't be done as things currently stand. You can't put HTML in your Gmail signature. Frankly, I think this is a good thing. I wouldn't want someone dropping IFRAMES or SCRIPT tags in e-mail to me.

Someone may be able to come up with a way to dynamically create an image from this, but it won't have links and may not work well all of the time.

So, unless and until Google implements this I'd say it's not currently possible.

Comment: So you think it should be suggested as a Gmail labs idea?

Comment: I think it seems like a reasonable feature to add. Personally, I don't like HTML e-mail and really don't like big signature blocks, but that's just me.

Comment: This could work as a labs or something, as long as it's blocked along with all other pictures with the current gmail feature to block pictures in emails.

Answer (score 0):

I have been happy with the free version of http://www.wisestamp.com/, which has plugins for most browsers and Thunderbird.

Comment: This looks good but I don't want an ad/paid solution and I want my actual profile badge.

Comment: TL;DR - Your mileage may vary.

I'm not paying the subscription for WS, and I have no ads in my sig. The signature is hackable HTML, so it isn't impossible to get the Google Profile badge as static content, but I see how that is not what you are asking for. I'm not holding my breath for Google to add this feature, but it's worth a shot and I'll upvote it.